# PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "TableName" Position: 1

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

Hi I am trying to execute a native SQL query but getting the exception as below

The query i am trying to execute is as below:

```
public List<Category> getAllCategories(){
    List<Category> categories = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("Category.getAllAfterMerge", Category.class).getResultList();
    return categories;
}
```

and the NamedNative Query is as below

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name="Category.getAllAfterMerge", query="SELECT C.ID, C.CODE, COALESCE(R.DISPLAY_NAME, C.NAME) as NAME, C.PARENT_ID, C.PATH, C.COMP_ID, C.CREATED_ON, C.MODIFIED_ON FROM CATEGORY C LEFT JOIN REFERENCE_VALUES R ON C.ID = R.REFERENCE_VALUE_CODE AND R.REFERENCE_OBJ_NAME = 'CATEGORY';")
```

The Tables are as below

```
CREATE TABLE category
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  code text NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  parent_id bigint,
  path text,
  comp_id bigint,
  created_on timestamp without time zone,
  modified_on timestamp without time zone,
)
```

And the Reference_Values table is as below

```
CREATE TABLE reference_values
(
  id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  reference_obj_name text,
  reference_value_code bigint,
  display_name text,
  created_on timestamp without time zone,
  modified_on timestamp without time zone,
)
```

The entities are as below Category.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category") 
@NamedNativeQuery(name="Category.getAllAfterMerge", query="SELECT C.ID, C.CODE, COALESCE(R.DISPLAY_NAME, C.NAME) as NAME, C.PARENT_ID, C.PATH, C.COMP_ID, C.CREATED_ON, C.MODIFIED_ON FROM CATEGORY C LEFT JOIN REFERENCE_VALUES R ON C.ID = R.REFERENCE_VALUE_CODE AND R.REFERENCE_OBJ_NAME = 'CATEGORY';")
public class Category extends Persistent {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManyToOne
private Category parent;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
private Set<Category> children;

private String code;

private String name;

private String path;

@Column(name = "comp_id")
private Integer compId;
```

And the ReferenceValues.java as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reference_values")
@NamedQuery(name = "ReferenceValues.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM ReferenceValues r")
public class ReferenceValues extends Persistent implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "display_name")
private String displayName;

@Column(name = "reference_obj_name")
private String referenceObjName;

@Column(name = "reference_value_code")
private Long referenceValueCode;
```

exception is as below:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:492)
at getAllCategories(JpaCategoryDAO.java:18)
at CategoryServiceImplTest.testGetAllCategories(CategoryServiceImplTest.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:670)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2115)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1898)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1874)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2610)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2593)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2422)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2417)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1980)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322)
at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
... 31 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "Category"
  Position: 1
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2003)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:200)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:424)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:161)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
... 46 more
```

Comment: Does this query run without issues in your native Postgres database?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes the query runs in postgres.

Comment: Can you enable hibernate.show_sql flag and see what hibernate is actually executing.

Comment: @SangramJadhav ill just try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `createNamedQuery()` method for the named queries and add `resultClass` to the `@NamedNativeQuery`

```
List<Category> categories = getEntityManager()
   .createNamedQuery("Category.getAllAfterMerge").getResultList();

@NamedNativeQuery(name = "Category.getAllAfterMerge",
  query = "SELECT C.ID, C.CODE, COALESCE(R.DISPLAY_NAME, C.NAME) as NAME,
  C.PARENT_ID, C.PATH, C.COMP_ID, C.CREATED_ON, C.MODIFIED_ON 
  FROM CATEGORY C LEFT JOIN REFERENCE_VALUES R ON C.ID =  
  R.REFERENCE_VALUE_CODE AND R.REFERENCE_OBJ_NAME = 'CATEGORY'", 
  resultClass = Category.class)
```

Probably, you need to use quotes for the aliases

`COALESCE(R.DISPLAY_NAME, C.NAME) as \"NAME\"`

Comment: adding resultClass = Category.class  solved the problem.

Comment: @praveen I am very glad. Thanks for accepting the answer. :)